# Another way to evaluate the nested radical $x=\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots}}}}$

Tags: nested-radicals

Consider the following expression:
$$x=\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots}}}}$$
It can easily be evaluated by realizing that:
$$x=\sqrt{2+x}$$
After squaring both sides and solving the quadratic equation, we find that $x=2$. But my question is: out of curiosity, is there any other way to evaluate this nested radical? Perhaps one involving infinite series/products?

Comment: Of course your solution is incomplete.  It shows only *if* it converges, *then* it converges to $2$.  You also need to show somehow that it converges.

Comment: And if we observe that $$
\sqrt{2}\approx 1.4142 $$ $$ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\approx 1.8478 $$ $$ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}\approx 1.9616 $$
$$
\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}\approx 1.9904 $$ $$ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}}\approx 1.9976?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Prove by induction that

$$\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots\sqrt{2}}}}}=2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$

where $n$ is the number of roots.

**P.S.** If I am not mistaken, this can be interpreted geometrically as follows:

If $A_1A_2....A_{2^n}$ is a regular polynomial with $A_1A_2=1$ then 
$$A_1A_3=\sqrt{2+{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\ldots\sqrt{2}}}}}$$

Now, as  $n$ increases the angle $A_2$ gets closer and closer to $180$ and hence $A_1A_3$ gets closer and closer to $A_1A_2+A_2A_3$.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!